# Send emails through Gmail without asking for permission to read emails (Google API)

Tags: google-api, gmail

When sending emails through the API. Is it possible to only ask for permission only to send, and not to read?

I want to make sure my users inbox is not read, but want to offer the posibility to send emails on their behalf.

All i've seen so far is that you either give permission to both, or none.

Answer (score 0):

Send requires write access, write access comes with read access.

so no you are going to need full access to send an email